# It seems like Gulp keeps watching after process is dead

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, gulp, gulp-watch

I've been trying Ionic these times and I have a recurring problem that I can't explain : after a few `ionic serve`s I get this error message

```
Running live reload server: undefined
Watching: 0=www/**/*, 1=!www/lib/**/*
Live Reload failed to start, error: Error: watch {myfolder} ENOSPC
Ionic serve failed - error: Error: watch {myfolder} ENOSPC
```

Now of course I have searched every bit of this error message and got this **ABSOLUTELY AWFUL** solution proposition :

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

This solution tells me I have to allow Gulp to watch a tremendous amount of files so I don't have this problem, people stating this solution say that other programs like DropBox might already be watching too many files but I don't have DrobBox or any other program that should watch my files and I only installed Gulp because it was required by Ionic. I Also tried to kill any process related to gulp, ionic, cordova, Node.JS but Gulp is still watching too many files for me to test my goddamn app.

I usually fix this by restarting my computer but there **HAS** to be a real way to solve this right ?